# Is the Preston Garvey impersonator good for anything specific?

Tags: fallout-4

In *Fallout 4*, I ran into a person impersonating Preston Garvey. I had Dogmeat as my companion at the time of the encounter. Is the impersonator good for anything specific, or is there any interesting dialogue if you have Preston with you?

Comment: After you've got the answer, head over to the new settlement that needs your help. I've marked it on your map, general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it doesn't provide any interesting dialogue

Comment: How could confronting an imposter not be interesting dialogue? Did you mean to say that having Preston with doesn't present any additional dialogue?

Answer (score 4):

The Preston Garvey impersonator is just a random encounter - a scam artist attempting to make some quick caps by playing off the goodwill of the Minutemen.

The player has a few options:

- Hand over the requested 100 caps
- Refuse to hand over the caps
- Claim (truthfully or otherwise) to be the Minutemen General.
- Claim to know the real Preston Garvey.

Having been 'found out', the impersonator will attempt to flee from you if you choose the latter two options.

Disappointingly, the real Preston Garvey has no unique dialogue to offer before, during or after the encounter, even if you encounter the impersonator with Preston as your companion.

Some info from personal experience and some from the [Fallout 4 Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Preston_Garvey_impersonator)